# CSS + Bootstrap issue with column and footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I put a `<div class="col-md****">` (inside the `<div class="container">` the **footer** goes to the top like if it had **float** propertie and is not. I use Bootstrap 3 and you can test the same in the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/j90xvLxy/

Note that if you maximize the result it the **footer** will change and be on the right of the **form**.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I corrected it by adding the class `.col-md-12` to the **footer** element and it stays on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem, you needed to add positioning to your footer, Here is an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j90xvLxy/2/

```
  .footer{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0px;}
```

Let me know if that works :)

Comment: you can appreciate them in the fiddle you shared.